# Average Function Not Finding Correct Average C++

Tags: c++

```
float findGradeAvg(GradeType array, int numOfGrades)

{
    float sum = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++)

       sum = sum + array[i];

    return (sum / numOfGrades); 
}
```

The above is my code for finding the average of the inputted grades. The function skeleton cannot be changed, so I am stuck with using a float and two inputs.

Here is my main:

```
int main()

{
    StringType30 firstname, lastname;  // two arrays of characters defined
    int numOfGrades;                   // holds the number of grades
    GradeType  grades;                 // grades is defined as a one dimensional array 
    float average;                     // holds the average of a student's grade
    char moreinput;                    // determines if there is more input

    // Input the number of grades for each student

    cout << "Please input the number of grades each student will receive." << endl
         << "This number must be a number between 1 and " << MAXGRADE << " inclusive" << endl;

    cin >> numOfGrades;

    while (numOfGrades > MAXGRADE || numOfGrades < 1)
    {
        cout << "Please input the number of grades for each student." << endl
             << "This number must be a number between 1 and " << MAXGRADE << " inclusive" << endl;

        cin >> numOfGrades;

    }

    // Input names and grades for each student
    cout << "Please input a y if you want to input more students"
         << " any other character will stop the input" << endl;
    cin >> moreinput;

    while ( moreinput == 'y' || moreinput == 'Y')

    {
        cout << "Please input the first name of the student" << endl;
        cin >> firstname;
        cout << endl << "Please input the last name of the student" << endl;
        cin >> lastname;

        for (int count = 0; count < numOfGrades; count++)

        {

            cout << endl << "Please input a grade" << endl;
            int i = 0;
            cin >> grades[i];
            i++;

        }

        cout << firstname << ' ' << lastname << " has an average of "; 
        float average = findGradeAvg(grades, numOfGrades);
        cout << average;
        cout << "which gives the letter grade of " << findLetterGrade(average);

        cout << endl << endl << endl;
        cout << "Please input a y if you want to input more students"
             << " any other character will stop the input" << endl;
        cin >> moreinput;

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why it is giving the incorrect value for average because I used this function in a different program with the correct results. Right now I am inputting 100, 90, and 90, and am receiving the following as an output.

-7.15828e+007

Comment: What is `GradeType`? What's the value of `numOfGrades`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, A one-dimensional array of unspecified size.

Comment: A one-dimensional array of **what**

Comment: @chris *Hopefully* a one-dimensional array of unspecified (but large enough to fit all grades) size.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I sure hope so.

Comment: yes, it is an array of size [numOfGrades] so it expands to fit as many grades as is needed, though the max per student is 25.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a problem

```
for (int count = 0; count < numOfGrades; count++)
{
    cout << endl << "Please input a grade" << endl;
    int i = 0;
    cin >> grades[i];
    i++;
}
```

Here you define (and redefine over and over again) the variable `i` *inside* the loop! That means `i` will always be zero. You probably want e.g.

```
cin >> grades[count];
```

Comment: OMG! How did I not see that?? Thank you so much!